# Help with "exim wait-remote_smtp" at 99% cpu

Tags: centos, linux, web-applications, exim

I'm currently in the process of building up a web application.  However, I occasionally run into an issue where "usr/sbin/exim_tidydb /var/spool/exim wait-remote_smtp" suddenly jumps up to 99% cpu and prevents other processes of my application from running.

From what I understand Exim is a webmail service, however there are a very limited amount of emails being sent out from this application (certainly not enough to cause this).

What's going on and how can I prevent this from happening?

BTW: I'm running Centos v.5 on dedicated hardware with standard apache at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exim is a MTA, much like sendmail. The tidydb service is probably scheduled via cron.

My suggestion would be to modify the cron service (check /etc/cron[tab,.*] to run exim_tidydb when your server is typically not under high load, say 3am.

Comment: Sorry, still somewhat confused as to what the actual root of the issue is.

Comment: Your system is configured to run a very high cpu service during a time when your server is already under high utilization. In order to fix this, you'll need to reschedule the service to run at a different time, or move the mail server to its own machine.

Comment: So the "usr/sbin/exim_tidydb" requires 99% cpu to go about it's business?   Unfortunately their really isn't a downtime for my server as it has a very specific set of operations every hour.

Comment: yes, its a common problem (google: exim_tidydb cpu). You _could_ remove it from cron, but that may have adverse effects on your mail db.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was because of spammer mails.
I blocked the addresses with SpamAssassin.
If that's the case, go to `~/.spamassassin/user_prefs` file and add `blacklist_from    mail@spam.com`.
Then delete all of the spammer mails that are "stuck" in your server with the command `grep -lr mail@spam.com /var/spool/exim/input/* | xargs rm -rf`